# C++ Need Help for Class Declaration in Header

Tags: c++, class, header, declaration

I get stuck when trying to understand following code.

```
  class V8_EXPORT Utf8Value {
     public:
        explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj);
        ~Utf8Value();
        char* operator*() { return str_; }
        const char* operator*() const { return str_; }
        int length() const { return length_; }
     private:
        char* str_;
        int length_;

        Utf8Value(const Utf8Value&);
        void operator=(const Utf8Value&);
   };
```

1. Line: "~Utf8Value();"
   When I checked the cpp file, it contains only one line:

   ```
    String::Utf8Value::~Utf8Value() {
      i::DeleteArray(str_);
    }
   ```

Does it mean that the function is to delete the `char* str_`? Is there any reason why got a `~` before the function name? Can I rename it to other names instead of `~Utf8Value`?

2. Line: `const char* operator*() const { return str_; }`
   What does it do? Why there is a `*` after function name?
   My understanding of `const` is that the fucntion/variable will never change, but what does the second `const` after brackets mean?
3. Line: `Utf8Value(const Utf8Value&);`
   Is it another constructor like the first line `explicit Utf8Value(Local<v8::Value> obj);` ?
4. Line: `void operator=(const Utf8Value&);`
   I have no idea what this line is trying to do.

Can anyone help me with this? Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you!!

Comment: Those are basic questions about classes. Going through a textbook and working through the problems in it will be more useful to you in the long run than getting answers to these specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you do not know the C++ syntax well before you try to read some bigger project source code.

To your question:

1. A function start with '~' in class declaration (scope) is the Destroy function of a class object which call automatically when the object is die or deleted. In this case, An object of Utf8Value (let us call it object at next) have been hold a str_ pointing to somewhere that need to free when the host being destroying. Get to give, give to get. Finally, you can not rename it.
2. This line declares a behavior when treat this object as a char* string. What does it did this here call operator override in C++ and most operator can be designed as what you want, like arithmetic, compare, shift, etc. That is a very peculiar characteristics of C++. For the 'const' function, it means this function will not change something in this object.
3. Yes. But since it is declared in the private scope, it can NOT be called out of the object or another constructor. Generally speaking, it is designed to forbidding construct an object in a way that designer does not want.
4. It works like question 3 while trying to stop constructing an object from value assignment.